# Delete column from a numpy structured array (list of tuples in the array)?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I use an external library function which returns a numpy structured array.

```
cities_array
>>> array([ (1, [-122.46818353792992, 48.74387985436505], u'05280', u'Bellingham', u'53', u'Washington', u'5305280', u'city', u'N', -99, 52179),
       (2, [-109.67985528815007, 48.54381826401885], u'35050', u'Havre', u'30', u'Montana', u'3035050', u'city', u'N', 2494, 10201),
       (3, [-122.63068540357023, 48.49221584868184], u'01990', u'Anacortes', u'53', u'Washington', u'5301990', u'city', u'N', -99, 11451),
       ...,
       (3147, [-156.45657614262274, 20.870633142444376], u'22700', u'Kahului', u'15', u'Hawaii', u'1522700', u'census designated place', u'N', 7, 16889),
       (3148, [-156.45038252004554, 20.76059218396], u'36500', u'Kihei', u'15', u'Hawaii', u'1536500', u'census designated place', u'N', -99, 11107),
       (3149, [-155.08472452266503, 19.693112205773275], u'14650', u'Hilo', u'15', u'Hawaii', u'1514650', u'census designated place', u'N', 38, 37808)], 
      dtype=[('ID', '<i4'), ('Shape', '<f8', (2,)), ('CITY_FIPS', '<U5'), ('CITY_NAME', '<U40'), ('STATE_FIPS', '<U2'), ('STATE_NAME', '<U25'), ('STATE_CITY', '<U7'), ('TYPE', '<U25'), ('CAPITAL', '<U1'), ('ELEVATION', '<i4'), ('POP1990', '<i4')])
```

The `cities_array` is of type `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

I am able to access individual columns of the array:

```
cities_array[['ID','CITY_NAME']]
>>> array([(1, u'Bellingham'), (2, u'Havre'), (3, u'Anacortes'), ...,
       (3147, u'Kahului'), (3148, u'Kihei'), (3149, u'Hilo')], 
      dtype=[('ID', '<i4'), ('CITY_NAME', '<U40')])
```

Now I want to delete the first column, `ID`. The [help](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) and [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632568/remove-a-specific-column-in-numpy) say it should be `numpy.delete`.

When running this: `numpy.delete(cities_array,cities_array['ID'],1)` I get the error message:

```
...in delete
    N = arr.shape[axis]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I post-process the cities_array to be able to work with the array?

I am on Python 2.7.10 and numpy 1.11.0

Comment: As shown in the answer you can view a subset of the dtype names. It's not a true delete.  There is also a library of recfuncs that might implement a deleting copy.

Comment: numpy.lib.recfunctions.drop_fields

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks for the comment, good to know there is an external library for that. But isn't it strange that such a basic operation fails? Just a simple array `x = numpy.zeros(3, dtype={'names':['col1', 'col2'], 'formats':['i4','f4']})` fails to delete a column with `numpy.delete(x,0,1)`. What is the rout cause of this issue, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You comment:

> But isn't it strange that such a basic operation fails? Just a simple array `x = numpy.zeros(3, dtype={'names':['col1', 'col2'], 'formats':['i4','f4']})` fails to delete a column with `numpy.delete(x,0,1)`. What is the rout cause of this issue, any ideas?

`np.delete` isn't a basic operation.  Look at it's code.  It's 5 screens long (on Ipython).  A lot of that handles the different ways that you can specify the delete elements.

For 
    np.delete(x, 0, axis=1)

it uses a special case

```
    # optimization for a single value
    ...
    newshape[axis] -= 1
    new = empty(newshape, arr.dtype, arrorder)
    slobj[axis] = slice(None, obj)
    new[slobj] = arr[slobj]
    slobj[axis] = slice(obj, None)
    slobj2 = [slice(None)]*ndim
    slobj2[axis] = slice(obj+1, None)
    new[slobj] = arr[slobj2]
```

For a 2d array, and axis=1 it does:

```
new = np.zeros((x.shape[0], x.shape[1]-1), dtype=x.dtype)
new[:, :obj] = x[:, :obj]
new[:, obj:] = x[:, obj+1:]
```

In other words, it allocates a new array with 1 less column, and then copies two slices from the original to it.

With multiple delete columns and boolean `obj` it takes other routes.

Notice that fundamental to that action is the ability to index the 2 dimensions.

But you can't index your `x` that way.  `x[0,1]` gives a `too many indices` error.  You have to use `x[0]['col1']`.  Indexing the fields of a `dtype` is fundamentally different from indexing the columns of a 2d array.

The `recfunctions` manipulate the `dtype` fields in ways that regular `numpy` functions don't.  Based on previous study, I'm guessing that `drop_field` does something like this:

```
In [57]: x    # your x with some values
Out[57]: 
array([(1, 3.0), (2, 2.0), (3, 1.0)], 
      dtype=[('col1', '<i4'), ('col2', '<f4')])
```

Target array, with different `dtype` (missing one field)

```
In [58]: y=np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=x.dtype.descr[1:])
```

copy values, field by field:

```
In [60]: for name in y.dtype.names:
    ...:     y[name]=x[name]
In [61]: y
Out[61]: 
array([(3.0,), (2.0,), (1.0,)], 
      dtype=[('col2', '<f4')])
```

Regular n-d indexing is built around the `shape` and `strides` attributes.  With these (and the element byte size) it can quickly identify the location in the `data` buffer of a desired element.

With a compound `dtype`, shape and strides work the same way, but `nbytes` is different.  In your `x` case it is 24 - 12 each for the `i4` and `f4` fields.  So regular indexing steps from one 24 bit record to the next.  So to select the  'col2' field, it has take the further step of selecting the 2nd set of 4 bytes within each record.

Where possible I think it translates field selection into regular indexing.  `__array_interface__` is a nice dictionary of the essential attributes of an array.

```
In [70]: x.__array_interface__
Out[70]: 
{'data': (68826112, False),
 'descr': [('col1', '<i4'), ('col2', '<f4')],
 'shape': (3,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '|V8',
 'version': 3}

In [71]: x['col2'].__array_interface__
Out[71]: 
{'data': (68826116, False),
 'descr': [('', '<f4')],
 'shape': (3,),
 'strides': (8,),
 'typestr': '<f4',
 'version': 3}
```

The second array points to the same data buffer, but 4 bytes further along (the first `col2` value).  In effect it is a view.

(`np.transpose` is another function that does not operate across the `dtype` boundary.)

===================

Here's the code for `drop_fields` (summarized):

```
In [74]: from numpy.lib import recfunctions  # separate import statement
In [75]: recfunctions.drop_fields??

def drop_fields(base, drop_names, usemask=True, asrecarray=False):
    .... # define `drop_descr function
    newdtype = _drop_descr(base.dtype, drop_names)
    output = np.empty(base.shape, dtype=newdtype)
    output = recursive_fill_fields(base, output)
    return output
```

`recursive_fill_fields` does a name by name field copy, and is able to handle dtypes that define fields within fields (the recursive part).

```
In [81]: recfunctions.drop_fields(x, 'col1')
Out[81]: 
array([(3.0,), (2.0,), (1.0,)], 
      dtype=[('col2', '<f4')])

In [82]: x[['col2']]  # multifield selection that David suggests
Out[82]: 
array([(3.0,), (2.0,), (1.0,)], 
      dtype=[('col2', '<f4')])

In [83]: x['col2']     # single field view
Out[83]: array([ 3.,  2.,  1.], dtype=float32)
```

`drop_field` produces a similar result as the multifield indexing that @David suggests.  However that multifield indexing is poorly developed, as you will see if you try some sort of assignment.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this should work:

```
def delete_colum(array, *args):

    filtered = [x for x in array.dtype.names if x not in args]

    return array[filtered]
```

Example with array:

```
a
Out[9]: 
array([(1, [-122.46818353792992, 48.74387985436505])], 
      dtype=[('ID', '<i4'), ('Shape', '<f8', (2,))])

delete_colum(a,'ID')
Out[11]: 
array([([-122.46818353792992, 48.74387985436505],)], 
      dtype=[('Shape', '<f8', (2,))])
```